# Problem to access my domain in digitalocean

Tags: ruby-on-rails, server, digital-ocean

i have an issue trying to access to my domain. I have my app (rails app) hosted in digital ocean droplet i have configured nginx files in sites-available and sites-enabled but every time i want to connect to my main domain it gets an infinitive loading state and it never shows. into my sites-available i got this configuration:

```
    server {
        server_name devprimate.com www.devprimate.com;

        location / {
            proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        }


    }
```

to connect start the rails server i user rails s (instead of rails s + ip address)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found the answer, since i've installed ssl yesterday i forgot to set up a new rule with the firewall in digitalocean.

it was not accepting https traffic so i did this step:

1. sudo ufw status -> to check which rules i have added in the past.
2. sudo ufw allow 'Nginx HTTP'

**the 2nd rule fixed my problem! :D**